# Decimal value format not getting for mpandoidchart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, decimalformat

I am using [mpandroidchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpandroidchart). I am using `YAxisValueFormatter` to format my value like `0.00` in my chart but i am getting simple value like `123`.Not geeting two zero after my value like `123.00`.
please see image to get more idea.

[image]

```
class MyYAxisValueFormatter implements YAxisValueFormatter {

private DecimalFormat mFormat;

public MyYAxisValueFormatter() {
    mFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
}

@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value, YAxis yAxis) {
    return mFormat.format(value) + "$";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mFormat = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
```

or

```
mFormat = new DecimalFormat("$###.##");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine (although I recommend the format `#0.00`, because values less then 1 will show as `.45$` instead of `0.45$`)

Are you sure that you have set the formatter on the chart like this example?

```
YAxis leftAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setValueFormatter(new MyYAxisValueFormatter());
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this,

mFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

with this

mFormat = new DecimalFormat(".00");

It is working for me.